# Azure Devops Agent Pipeline install pip fails

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm building a azure devops pipeline, to deploy an databricks notebook, however, before I get to that step I need to install a few things.

In a bash step I have the following

```
echo "Updating pip"
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I've also tried the following

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Both yield the same error log that:

```
2020-07-07T09:19:21.9087970Z Updating pip
2020-07-07T09:19:22.8470016Z Collecting pip
2020-07-07T09:19:23.1307705Z   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/84/23ed6a1796480a6f1a2d38f2802901d078266bda38388954d01d3f2e821d/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
2020-07-07T09:19:23.4814923Z Installing collected packages: pip
2020-07-07T09:19:24.3589221Z Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
2020-07-07T09:19:24.5176900Z You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.1.1 is available.
2020-07-07T09:19:24.5178120Z You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I'm a puzzled by the fact that the output showes that it is installing `pip-8.1.1`, when it is clearly downloading the newest version (`20.1.1`) of pip.

I'm clearly missing something.
Thanks for your time and help in advance!

Comment: try  python3 -m pip -q install --upgrade pip setuptools

Comment: Thanks, however, the error is still the same as above.

Comment: Try adding --user to your python3 command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding a step before the bash script to select Python

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.8'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.8
```

According to the log it is merely adding a path env variable to PATH

```
2020-07-07T13:02:27.1599357Z Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.3/x64
2020-07-07T13:02:27.1607326Z Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.3/x64/bin
```

After adding the above step I get the following log

```
2020-07-07T13:02:31.6513097Z Collecting pip
2020-07-07T13:02:31.7236234Z   Downloading pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
2020-07-07T13:02:32.0470915Z Installing collected packages: pip
2020-07-07T13:02:32.0471385Z   Attempting uninstall: pip
2020-07-07T13:02:32.0484694Z     Found existing installation: pip 20.1.1
2020-07-07T13:02:32.2325914Z     Uninstalling pip-20.1.1:
2020-07-07T13:02:32.2701613Z       Successfully uninstalled pip-20.1.1
2020-07-07T13:02:33.4108823Z Successfully installed pip-20.1.1
```

This solved my problem of updating pip (though Python 3 already had the latest version), and made me able to run the next steps too.